# Composer Seems to Have Cached a Typo. How to clear it?

Tags: composer-php

I was running this command:

```
composer require dingo/api:1.0.x@dev
```

But I misspelled it the first time as such:

```
composer require dingo/zpi:1.0.x@dev
```

However, even though I fixed the error (changed zpi to api), I still get the same error everytime I try to run the command:

```
Problem 1
    - The requested package dingo/zpi could not be found in any version, there may be a typo in the package name.
```

I thought maybe running:

```
Composer clear-cache
```

Would resolve it, but no dice.  Any other way to clear this error out of the system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open `composer.json` in your project folder and remove the wrong entry in the `require` section for `dingo/zpi:1.0.x@dev`. Then you should be able to run `composer install` or `composer update` without problems.

The command `composer require dingo/zpi:1.0.x@dev` just adds an requirement in `composer.json` and runs `composer install`. After you run `composer require dingo/api:1.0.x@dev` a second requirement was added to `composer.json` but the first one which was wrong wasn't removed.

Comment: Yup.  Thanks much!